# How can I debug an Angular 9 compilation error with IVY enabled?

Tags: angular, angular-ivy, angular-builder, angular9

Currently I am updating a project to Angular 9. Unfortunately I can not build it with IVY. The error message is

> ERROR in Cannot resolve type entity ɵngcc14.ɵu to symbol

Without disabled IVY the project builds and serves properly. I think, it is caused by an external library. What I was wondering is if there is the possibility to print additional logging or debugging information to the console or if there are any log-files in order to figure out which of these dependencies causes the error. Do you have any idea?

My dependencies are

```json
"@angular/animations": "~9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/common": "~9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/compiler": "~9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/core": "~9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/fire": "^5.3.0-rc.2",
"@angular/forms": "~9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/material": "^9.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/platform-server": "^9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/pwa": "^0.900.0-rc.6",
"@angular/router": "~9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/service-worker": "^9.0.0-rc.6",
"@nestjs/common": "^6.10.1",
"@nestjs/core": "^6.10.1",
"@nestjs/ng-universal": "^2.0.1",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.10.1",
"@ngrx/effects": "^8.5.2",
"@ngrx/entity": "^8.5.2",
"@ngrx/router-store": "^8.5.2",
"@ngrx/store": "^8.5.2",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.5.2",
"@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.1.1",
"angular-plotly.js": "^1.4.2",
"core-js": "^3.4.2",
"d3": "^5.14.2",
"documentations": "^9.0.0",
"firebase": "^7.6.0-1",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"katex": "^0.11.1",
"plotly.js": "^1.51.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
"rxjs": "~6.5.3",
"tslib": "^1.10.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
```

Thanks and cheers!

Comment: Since IVY is still a big Work in progress right now there isn't a way to have a verbose output. What I can suggest is to create a new blank project with the same dependencies and, removing few of them at run, trying to compile to understand which library(ies) is/are causing this issue.